# How to hack an R-style list in C++?

Tags: c++, r, list, vector

I have a problem for which I want to create a data structure that is something like an R-style list in C++.  The structure is something like a matrix that can hold rows of variable sizes.  It's a C++ assignment so I can't actually do this in R itself.

I thought about this this way:

- each "level" of the list is a C++ vector of char
- there is a vector of pointers, each one pointing to a different level of the list.

I know how to create each of the level vectors individually, but don't know how to connect them to the pointer vector so that they could be accessed.  Also, what C++ syntax would I use to access a particular element in a level, e.g. if I wanted to access the third element of the second level, in R it would be something like Levels[[2]]$elements[3].  How is this done in C++?

Comment: This is going to be a painful way of learning C++.  Get a C++ book, learn the language.  Then you will be better equipped to understand how concepts expressed in one language can be represented in a different language.

Comment: How about... ``#include <vector>  typedef std::vector<char> Row_t; typedef std::vector<Row_t> RLikeSomething_t;``? You can access then like this: ``RLikeSomething_t something; .... something[row][column] = 'x';``

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example in which I used Rcpp *simply to ease the compilation of the example*: all data types are STL types (though we use implicit conversion to get the list back):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]

std::list<std::vector<double> > ex(std::vector<double> a,
                                   std::vector<double> b) {

  std::list<std::vector<double> > l;
  l.push_back(a);
  l.push_back(b);

  return l;
}

/*** R
v <- sqrt(1:5)
w <- log(3:5)
ex(v, w)
***/
```

You can source this directly into R to have it *compiled*, then *linked* and *loaded* as well as having the example at the end *run*:

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("/tmp/ex.cpp")

R> v <- sqrt(1:5)

R> w <- log(3:5)

R> ex(v, w)
[[1]]
[1] 1.00000 1.41421 1.73205 2.00000 2.23607

[[2]]
[1] 1.09861 1.38629 1.60944

R>
```

So this should pass your requirements as having a list container over two vectors of different length.

You may find the [Rcpp documentation](http://www.rcpp.org) helpful for going back and forth between R and C++ --- but I second the comment by DavidO that you also need to learn C++ itself.

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of the assignment, which was to simulate the stacking and unstacking of a pile of blocks (2D only, thankfully), here is what I finally came up with (see below).  A level of the pile is represented by a vector of chars, while the different levels of the pile are handled by a vector of pointers to PileLevels.  It took me a bit of time but I finally understood that one can push pointers on a container class just like any other data type.

First a class to define and handle operations on one level of a pile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class PileLevel
{

public:
    vector<char> elements;

    char GetLevelElement(int i);
    void SetLevelElement(int i, char newelt);
    void PushLevelElement(char newelt);
    char PopLevelElement();
    int GetLevelSize();
    void PrintLevel();
    void ClearLevel();
    bool isLevelEmpty();
};

char PileLevel::GetLevelElement(int i)
{
    return elements.at(i);
}

void PileLevel::SetLevelElement(int i, char newelt)
{
    elements.at(i) = newelt;
}

void PileLevel::PushLevelElement(char newelt)
{
    elements.push_back(newelt);
}

int PileLevel::GetLevelSize()
{
    return elements.size();
}

char PileLevel::PopLevelElement()
{
    int lst = GetLevelSize();
    //cout << lst << endl;
    char eltToRet = elements[lst-1];
    //cout << eltToRet << endl;
    elements.pop_back();
    return eltToRet;
}

void PileLevel::PrintLevel()
{
    int ctr=0;
    for (ctr = 0; ctr < GetLevelSize(); ctr++)
    {
        cout << elements.at(ctr) << " " ;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void PileLevel::ClearLevel()
{
    elements.clear();
}

bool PileLevel::isLevelEmpty()
{
    if (elements.size() == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Next, a class to handle the operations for the pile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "PileLevel.h"

using namespace std;

class BlockPile
{
public:
    vector<PileLevel*> Levels;
    int PileHeight;

    //constructor and destructor
    BlockPile();
    ~BlockPile();

    //helper functions
    void PrintPile();
    int GetPileHeight();
    void AddLevel();
    void AddLevel(char newElt);
    char PopLvlElt(int lvl);
    void PopEntireLevel(int lvl);
    void DeleteTopLevel();
    bool isPileEmpty();
    void PushLvlElt(char block, int lvl);
    void TryStackOnNewTopLevel(char block);
    void TryStackOnLowerLevel(char block, int lvl);
    void unStackPile();

    //required functions
    void clear();
    bool isEmpty();
    char unStack();
    char topBlock();
    void stack(char block);
    int numBlocks();
};

//BlockPile::BlockPile()  //test constructor to make sure basic push capabilities are working
//{
//  PileLevel* base = new PileLevel;
//  base->PushLevelElement('A');
//  base->PushLevelElement('B');
//  base->PushLevelElement('C');
//  Levels.push_back(base);
//  PileLevel* L1 = new PileLevel;
//  L1->PushLevelElement('D');
//  L1->PushLevelElement('E');
//  L1->PushLevelElement('F');
//  Levels.push_back(L1);
//}

BlockPile::BlockPile()
{
    PileLevel* base = new PileLevel;
    base->PushLevelElement('A');
    Levels.push_back(base);
}

BlockPile::~BlockPile()
{
    while (! isPileEmpty() )
    {
        DeleteTopLevel();
    }
}


int BlockPile::GetPileHeight()
{
    //cout << "Pile is:  " << Levels.size() << " levels high." << endl;
    return Levels.size();
}

void BlockPile::PrintPile()
{
    int ctr = 0;
    int lim = GetPileHeight();
    //cout << lim << endl;
    if (! isPileEmpty())
    {
        for (ctr = 0; ctr < lim; ctr++)
        {
            Levels[ctr]->PrintLevel();
        }  
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Can't print empty pile." << endl;
}

void BlockPile::AddLevel()  //add an empty level
{
    PileLevel* nuLevel = new PileLevel;
    Levels.push_back(nuLevel);
}

void BlockPile::AddLevel(char newElt)  //add a new level with one element pushed
{
    PileLevel* nuLevel = new PileLevel;
    nuLevel->PushLevelElement(newElt);
    Levels.push_back(nuLevel);
}

void BlockPile::DeleteTopLevel()
{
    PileLevel* delPtr;
    int ht = GetPileHeight();

    if (! isPileEmpty())
    {
        delPtr = Levels[ht-1];  //set a pointer to the top level 
        Levels[ht-1]->ClearLevel(); //clear any remaining data in the top level
        Levels[ht-1] = NULL; //disconnect the level from the vector of levels
        delete delPtr; //delete the level
        Levels.pop_back(); //pop the pointer to the level
    }
    else
        cout << "Pile is empty." << endl;
}

char BlockPile::PopLvlElt(int lvl)
{   char eltToRet;

    eltToRet = Levels[lvl]->PopLevelElement();
    //cout << Levels[lvl]->GetLevelSize() << endl;

    //must take these steps to clean up the pile if element popped was the only item remaining on the level
    if (Levels[lvl]->GetLevelSize() == 0)
    {
        vector<PileLevel*>::iterator ptVecIter = Levels.begin();  //need to declare this iterator and use .begin() because .erase() is defined to take iterator arguments
        Levels.erase(Levels.begin() + (lvl));  
    }
    return eltToRet;
}

void BlockPile::PopEntireLevel(int lvl)
{
    while (! Levels[lvl]->GetLevelSize() <= 0)
    {
        cout << Levels[lvl]->PopLevelElement() << " " ;
    }
    //must take these steps to clean up the pile if element popped was the only item remaining on the level
    if (Levels[lvl]->GetLevelSize() == 0)
    {
        vector<PileLevel*>::iterator ptVecIter = Levels.begin();  //need to declare this iterator and use .begin() because .erase() is defined to take iterator arguments
        Levels.erase(Levels.begin() + (lvl));  
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void BlockPile::PushLvlElt(char block, int lvl)
{
    if (Levels[lvl]->GetLevelSize() >= 0) //if the current level exists and contains 0 or more elements
        Levels[lvl]->PushLevelElement(block);
    else if (Levels[lvl] == NULL) //if pointer to current level is NULL
    {
        Levels[lvl] = new PileLevel;
        Levels[lvl]->PushLevelElement(block);
    }
    else if (lvl > GetPileHeight())  //if lvl is greater than current height of pile
    {
        AddLevel(block);  //add a new level to the pile and push the block on it
    }
}


bool BlockPile::isPileEmpty()
{
    if (Levels.size() == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void BlockPile::unStackPile()
{
    int lim = GetPileHeight() - 1;

    while (lim > -1)
    {
        PopEntireLevel(lim);
        lim--;
    }
}

void BlockPile::TryStackOnNewTopLevel(char block)
{
    int oldTopLvl = GetPileHeight()-1;  //get current top level of pile

    AddLevel();  //add a dummy new level but don't push anything on it yet
    int newTopLvl = GetPileHeight()-1;  //get new top level after adding dummy level

    int newTopLvlSize = Levels[newTopLvl]->GetLevelSize();  //should be 0
    int oldTopLvlSize = Levels[oldTopLvl]->GetLevelSize();  //should be > 0
    int sizeDiff = oldTopLvlSize - newTopLvlSize; 

    //cout << newTopLvlSize << "  " << oldTopLvlSize << "  " << sizeDiff << endl;

    if (sizeDiff >=2)  //if difference in size between dummy level and old top level is at least 2
        Levels[newTopLvl]->PushLevelElement(block);  //push the block on the new top level
    else
    {
        DeleteTopLevel();  //remove the dummy level, not ready for it yet
        TryStackOnLowerLevel(block,oldTopLvl);  //try to push the block on the next lower level 
    }
}

void BlockPile::TryStackOnLowerLevel(char block, int lvl)
{
    if (lvl == 0)  //if at level 0, base of the pile, can't go lower than this
    {
        Levels[lvl]->PushLevelElement(block);  //must push the block at the base
    }
    else //if not yet at base
    {
        int thisLvlSize = Levels[lvl]->GetLevelSize();  //get size of current level 
        int lowerLvlSize = Levels[lvl-1]->GetLevelSize(); //get size of next lower level 
        int sizeDiff = lowerLvlSize - thisLvlSize;  //difference in size

        //cout << thisLvlSize << "  " << lowerLvlSize << "  " <<  sizeDiff << endl;

        if (sizeDiff >= 2)  //if size difference is at least 2
            Levels[lvl]->PushLevelElement(block);  //push block on current level
        else  //if diff is smaller than 2
            TryStackOnLowerLevel(block,lvl-1);  //make recursive call and try to push it on a lower level
    }
}

//required functions
void BlockPile::clear()
{
    int lim = GetPileHeight()-1;

    while (lim > -1)
    {
        DeleteTopLevel();
        lim--;
    }
}

bool BlockPile::isEmpty()
{
    return isPileEmpty();
}

char BlockPile::unStack()
{
    int ht = GetPileHeight()-1;

    return PopLvlElt(ht);
}

char BlockPile::topBlock()
{
    int ht = GetPileHeight()-1;

    int lsize = Levels[ht]->GetLevelSize() - 1;

    return Levels[ht]->GetLevelElement(lsize);
}

void BlockPile::stack(char block)
{
    TryStackOnNewTopLevel(block);
}

int BlockPile::numBlocks()
{
    int acc = 0;
    int ht = GetPileHeight();
    int ctr;

    for(ctr = 0; ctr < ht; ctr++)
    {
        acc = acc + Levels[ctr]->GetLevelSize();
    }
    return acc;
}
```

And finally a driver program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

#include "BlockPile.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //PileLevel myLevel;

    //myLevel.PushLevelElement('A');
    //myLevel.PushLevelElement('B');
    //myLevel.PushLevelElement('C');
    //myLevel.PushLevelElement('D');

    //myLevel.PrintLevel();
    //cout << myLevel.GetLevelSize() << endl;
    //myLevel.PopLevelElement();
    //myLevel.PrintLevel();

    //BlockPile myPile;
    //myPile.GetPileHeight();
    //myPile.PrintPile();
    //myPile.AddLevel('Z');
    //myPile.GetPileHeight();
    //myPile.PrintPile();
    //myPile.PushLvlElt('P', 2);
    //myPile.PushLvlElt('Q', 1);
    //myPile.PrintPile();
    //cout << myPile.PopLvlElt(2) << endl;
    //cout << myPile.PopLvlElt(1) << endl;
    //cout << myPile.PopLvlElt(0) << endl;
    //myPile.PrintPile();
    //myPile.DeleteTopLevel();
    ////myPile.DeleteTopLevel();
    //myPile.PrintPile();
    //myPile.PushLvlElt('G',0);
    //myPile.PushLvlElt('H',0);
    //myPile.AddLevel('I');
    //myPile.PushLvlElt('J',2);
    //myPile.AddLevel('K');
    //myPile.PrintPile();
    ////myPile.PopEntireLevel(3);
    ////myPile.PopEntireLevel(2);
    //myPile.unStackPile();
    //myPile.PrintPile();

    //BlockPile myPile2;
    //myPile2.PrintPile();
    //myPile2.TryStackOnNewTopLevel('B');
    //myPile2.PrintPile();
    //myPile2.TryStackOnNewTopLevel('C');
    //myPile2.PrintPile();
    //myPile2.TryStackOnNewTopLevel('D');
    //myPile2.PrintPile();
    //myPile2.TryStackOnNewTopLevel('E');
    //myPile2.PrintPile();
    //myPile2.TryStackOnNewTopLevel('F');
    //myPile2.PrintPile();

    array<char,44> BlockSet = {'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '+', '-', '=', '/', '<', '>', '?', ',', '.'};
    int BSSize = BlockSet.size(); 
    int idx = 0;

    BlockPile myPile3;
    myPile3.PrintPile();
    //myPile3.clear();
    for (idx = 0; idx < BSSize; idx++)
    {
        myPile3.stack(BlockSet[idx]);
        cout << "Number of blocks currently in pile:  " << myPile3.numBlocks() << endl;
        myPile3.PrintPile();
    }

    cout << "Top block is:  " << myPile3.topBlock() << endl;
    cout << endl;

    for (idx=0; idx < 5; idx++)
    {
        cout << "Unstacking block:  "  << myPile3.unStack() << endl;
        cout << "Top block is now:  " << myPile3.topBlock() << endl;
        cout << "Number of blocks is now:  " << myPile3.numBlocks() << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Unstacking remainder of pile..." << endl;
    myPile3.unStackPile();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Voila.